# How are renormalization flow diagrams plotted from Beta function?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, renormalization

Say for example the beta function for Kondo model is
\begin{equation}
\beta(g)=-2g^2+2g^3+O(g^4)
\end{equation}
where $g=J\rho$

I see the flow usually plotted like this

[image]

and this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.04039 says that when the coupling constant $J$ is complex, the flow plot becomes

[image]

How are these diagrams plotted from the given equation?

Comment: For the first figure you first need to know $g$ as a function of $J_1$, $J_2$.  These are so-called stream plots (or streamline plots). Can be made using a variety of packages (matplotlib, Mathematica etc.). Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @Anyon, I think my question is :

From $\beta(J\rho)=(\rho J)^2+\frac{(\rho J)^3}{2}$, how is the relation between $J_r$ and $J_i$ found in the paper I linked

Comment: If you want to do complex $g$, you can use the MMA code `StreamPlot[ReIm[-2 g^2 + 2 g^3 /. g -> gr + I gi], {gr, -3, 3}, {gi, -3, 3}]`.

Comment: @user824530 I have only glanced at the paper you linked, but I would think $J_r$ and $J_i$ are the real and imaginary parts of the $J$ used in Eq. (4).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform, thanks! I am able to reproduce the second figure with that. 
Any idea on the first one? Here $g=J\rho$ is real and $J_1$ and $J_2$ are the transverse and longitudinal components of the coupling constant.